# How to properly return an overloaded operator ++ with a member variable?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am currently working on a project where my professor wants us to practice using overloaded operators, but the last one that is causing me trouble is the ++ increment one. I followed his examples, and examples that I have seen online and it does not throw any error messages on build, but it does not seem to work properly. It crashes the run and takes, the rating which was initialized at 0 to some random number. If I don't try to increment rating, then it doesn't cause any troubles and the overloaded << operator and works fine, I am at a loss right now.

This is my main so far

```
    list<int> time1{1000, 1200, 1400, 1600};
    list<int> time2{ 1100, 1300, 1500, 1700 };

    Cinema cinema;
    Movie * movie1 = new Movie("Superman", 1988, 11, 8);

    *movie1++;
    cout << * movie1;

    cinema.addMovie(movie1, time1);
```

This is the Movie Class

```
class Movie 
{
    public:
        Movie(const string & name, int yyyy, int mm, int dd) : name(name), releaseDate(Date(yyyy, mm, dd)) {};

        const Date getReleaseDate(); 
        // other? 
        bool operator < (Movie& r);
        bool operator == (Movie &); 
        Movie & operator ++ (); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, Movie &); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const Movie &); 

    private: 
        Movie() = default; 
        const Date releaseDate; 
        string name; 
        int rating = 0;
};
```

The cinema class if you find it relevant

```
class Cinema
{
    public: 
        Cinema() = default; 
        Cinema(Cinema &); 
        void addMovie(Movie *, list<int> & );
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, Cinema &); 
        //Movie * operator[](int); 
        void movieRunningAt(Movie &, list<int> & ); 
        void printShowTimes(const Movie *);
        void printAll() const;

    private:
        std::list<Movie *> movies;
        map<const Movie *, list<int>> movie_times;
};
```

The overloaded << operator that prints out the information, and works just fine if I do not try to use the overloaded ++ operator to increase rating

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, Movie & mo)
{
    os << mo.name << " released: " << mo.releaseDate << " rated " << mo.rating << "\n";
    return os;
}

////    The const version 

ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Movie & mo)
{
    os << mo.name << " released: " << mo.releaseDate << " rated " << mo.rating << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

And this is the ++ operator to increase the rating of the movie

```
Movie & Movie::operator ++ ()
{
    rating++;
    return *this;
}
```

Again, it doesn't throw any errors, but just, causes a bunch of random stuff to pop up, I think due to a memory leak of some kind, but I don't know for sure

Comment: Off topic... When ever you use `new` to `Dynamically allocate memory`, you should use `delete` keyword to `free` that memory, otherwise, it's memory leak. In this case, you should write `delete movie1;` at the end of your main function

Answer (score 2):

[Operator precedence in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Postfix operator `++` (post-increment) has higher precedence than  dereferencing operator `*`, so it is applied first.

`*movie1++;` will dereference `movie1` and discard the result, and then the pointer itself is incremented.

---

The preferred solution would be to not use pointers at all (but that requires changes in `Cinema` class)

```
Movie movie1 {"Superman", 1988, 11, 8};
movie1++;
cout << movie1;
```

Or you can change precedence using parantheses:

```
Movie * movie1 = new Movie("Superman", 1988, 11, 8);
(*movie1)++;
```

---

The next problem you will find is that you defined a pre-increment operator, not post-increment. The only valid usage now is `++(*movie1);`. A post-increment operator typically looks like this:

```
Movie Movie::operator ++ (int)
{
    Movie tmp = *this; //you need to make a copy to return it to the caller
    ++(*this); //use already defined pre-increment operator
    return tmp;
}
```